# finding Flow shop scheduling fitness

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I"m working with flow job scheduling issue. is there a mathematical equation to compute the fitness instead of the Gantt Chart ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the most common fitness measure would be the make span. Specifically you would be minimizing the total length of the schedule (Smaller make-span --> better fitness).